# Please help me improve my question

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-question

I got downvotes on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284381/i-develop-a-game-use-bluetooth-in-android) that I asked on Stack Overflow.

I don't understand why I got the downvotes and want to improve my question. Can anyone here please help me in this?

Comment: Regarding the edited question: people don't have to explain downvotes. Your question might be lacking code, have bad format/grammar etc.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd oh,I just want to know how to improve my question and add what information that maybe someone help me,:)

Comment: OK, fair enough. I read your question now and it's very unclear. Big part is because of bad English and grammar, unprofessional sentences like "and draw very slow ,yes ,sloooooow". Another big issue is that you did not ask any real question (and your question is about to be closed for that reason). Title like "I develop a game use bluetooth in android" is also very bad: people see this and think "cool, so this person develop a game. So what?". In short, you should really improve your question. Take your time, read other questions on the android tag that got upvotes and edit your question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thanks for your great(i don't know to choose which word)explanation,I will improve both my English and question gradually.Thanks again:D

Comment: No problem, looks like you just had a bad start here due to misunderstanding. I also edited this question of yours and hopefully it will get reopened, though it's not in my hands.

Comment: @HoneyAngry I have edited your question to improve the English, but I think your problem lies in the code that runs the bluetooth comms, not in your drawing routine. You need to edit in the correct code.

Answer (score 4):

Your original question (before being edited by other user) was very unclear. Big part is because of bad English and grammar, unprofessional sentences like "and draw very slow ,yes ,sloooooow".

Another big issue is that you did not ask any real question. Title like "I develop a game use bluetooth in android" is also very bad: people see this and think "cool, so this person develop a game. So what?".

In short, your original question needed a big improvement. Now that it's edited and improved, it already got 3 upvotes and if those who downvoted will come back they might undo their vote as well.

If you can further improve that question please do it, for future questions take your time, read other questions on the android tag that got upvotes and think well before posting.